# turning an element in array to a specific integer in C

Tags: c, cs50

I would like to pick a specific element in argv[] and assign it to an integer 'k.' I tried

```
int k = argv[1]
```

but it shows up some bugs.

I know that argv[1] can be something other than integer such as char. I think this is a problem but don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Then your next try may be `int k = atoi(argv[1]);`.

Comment: or, [`strtol()`.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Comment: "I know that argv[1] can be something other than integer such as char" `argv[1]`, if it exists and is a non-`NULL` value is *always* a pointer to a string. It will never be a simple integer value. C is statically typed, and `argv` has a type something like `char **`, so it will never be an integer directly.

Comment: `argv[1]` will never be an integer *or* a char. Specifically, it will be a `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All command line arguments are passed as *strings* - each `argv[i]` is a `char *` that points to the first character of a string.  If you call your program as

```
./foo 100
```

then `argv` contains:

```
argv[0] == address of the string "./foo"
argv[1] == address of the string "100"
argv[2] == NULL
```

To convert an element of `argv` to an integer you'll need to use a library function like `atoi` or `strtol`.  I prefer using `strtol` because it allows you to catch non-numeric characters and recover from bad input:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
char *chk; // will point to the first character *not* converted by strtol

int tmp = (int) strtol( argv[1], &chk, 10 ); // assuming base-10 input
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid integer, try again!\n", argv[1] );
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int k = tmp; 
// proceed as before
```

While it's redundant in this case, I advise assigning the result of `strtol` and similar conversion functions to a temporary variable, then make sure everything is valid before assigning to the intended target.

Comment: `isspace( *chk )` will invoke undefined behavior for negative character codes, unless the value happens to be equal to `EOF` (normally defined as `-1`). Therefore, you probably want to cast the function argument to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Thanks for the kind helps. Though I will have to study more to understand your answer :D !

Comment: In order to corroborate my previous comment about the posted code causing undefined behavior for negative `char` values (i.e. character codes above 127), here is a link to [§7.4 ¶1 of the ISO C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1). Also, [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) states the same thing. However, most common platforms define the behavior to be the expected behavior for negative values, except for `-1`, because in that case, the character code 255 is indistinguishable from `EOF` (assuming `EOF` is defined as `-1`).